# MYSQL NOT IN subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table

1. `item`
2. `confirmmasterdetail`

I want to select records from item table whose is not in confirmmasterdetail table 
when me run this query at that it's return empty result set.

```
SELECT itemId
,      itemName
FROM   item
LEFT 
JOIN   item /* HERE AN ALIAS IS MISSING, ITEM occurs twice. */
ON     item.itemId = confirmmasterdetail.itemId
WHERE  confirmmasterdetail.itemId 
       NOT IN 
       ( SELECT confirmmasterdetail.itemId
         FROM   confirmmasterdetail
       )
AND    confirmMasterId = ".$_REQUEST['confirmMasterId'];
```

Comment: Please indicate whether confirmmasterdetail.itemid is optional or required.

Answer (score 1):

See your query. Please prefix all columns selected with either table name or (better) add an alias to each table and use that one. Also note that `item` occurs twice in the query, so column names might not be what they seem to be.

Finally, ensure `null` can not be returned from the subselect.

Answer (score 1):

There is one important thing about `null` in SQL, it means `unknown` not `nothing`. So if your sub-query returns `null` values, it means `unknown`, and `not in unknown` makes DBMS to ignore all records.

Just change the subquery to:

```
SELECT confirmmasterdetail.itemId
  FROM confirmmasterdetail
 WHERE confirmmasterdetail.itemId is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your query has basic conceptual problems with SQL. It is hard to give advice without a clear statement of what you want and how the tables look like. To help you, we need at least information about the tables (what columns and how are they connected).

**Edit**: With the information you provided you might want to try one of these queries:

1. Select all items that have no corresponding entry in confirmmasterdetail:

   ```
   SELECT itemId
   ,      itemName
   FROM   item
   WHERE  item.itemId 
          NOT IN 
          ( SELECT confirmmasterdetail.itemId
            FROM   confirmmasterdetail
          );
   ```
2. Select all items that have no entry in confirmmasterdetail with the given confirmMasterId:

   ```
   SELECT itemId
   ,      itemName
   FROM   item
   WHERE  item.itemId 
          NOT IN 
          ( SELECT confirmmasterdetail.itemId
            FROM   confirmmasterdetail
            WHERE  confirmMasterId = ".$_REQUEST['confirmMasterId']
          );
   ```

Comment: in confirmMasterDetail i have this fields 
(1) confirmMasterDetailId (2) confirmMasterId (3) cDetailDate (4) itemId
(5) qty (6) partyId (7) rs (8) tax (9) totalRs in item table i have this 5 fields
  (1) itemId 
  (2) itemName
  (3) itemUnit
  (4) sequence
  (5) cSequence

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  i.*
FROM item i
  LEFT JOIN confirmmasterdetail c
    ON i.itemId = c.itemId
WHERE
  c.itemId IS NULL
```